# Different views for different customer types

Tags: magento-1.7, store-view, customer-group

Our website has 100 products.
We have 50 customers.
20 are friends group
30 are customer group

Is there a way so the friend group can see a specific 40 products, while the customer group can see all 100 products?

Comment: Yes it is possible but for that you have to buy extension of magento.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a product attribute, dropdown type, with values like : **Visible to Friends group** AND **Visible to All groups**. Now create an observer that checks for this attribute and prevent OR allow particular product to show at front.

Also, here is a FREE extension available that may help, [Groups Catalog 2](https://github.com/Vinai/groupscatalog2)

Comment: Do you happen to know if Groups Catalog 2 is still supported? I'm worried because it is no longer in Magento Connect. I tried installing the files manually and got some database errors so I removed it.  Any idea if it's still supported?